# Curl doesn't execute all commands sometimes

Tags: php, curl

Winging curl code and I have a lot of `preg_match_all();` and getting some data and url. Sometimes it processes it all, sometimes it misses some parts.

Is there any function to make it wait till all curl finish or speed up the process?

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file_path);   // Cookie management.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file_path); 

$result = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch); 

// Step3. parsing username
preg_match_all("#<span id=\"class\" class=\"tall\">(.*?)</span>#si", $result, $match);
```

and got alot 
`preg_match_all` commands there

Comment: unless you add some code it would be very hrad to detect what's exactly not working

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Comment: i said it's sometimes works sometimes not sorry i put my code

Comment: you're processing html with regexes and wondering why it doesn't work sometimes? ... http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/118068

Comment: cause i getting some data from urls inside url i think it takes sometimes to make this so i need function to speed up the process or give the curl the time to make all commands then execute others

Comment: regexes didn't make problem i am searching for this function